# Error al tomar e imprimir un arreglo de Strings en Java

Tags: java, array, matriz, vectores

Quisiera saber por qué no me está funcionando este programa. Trata de ordenar 4 tipos de datos. Nombre, Marca, Vencimiento y elaboración. Lo uso con dos bucles `for`, y quería saber porque no corre debidamente.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 int num_matriz;
        
      num_matriz= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de medicamentos a cargar"));
        
      String medicamentos_t [] [] = new String [num_matriz] [4];
      
      
      for (int a=0; a<=4; a++){
          for(int b=0; b<=num_matriz; b++){
           medicamentos_t [a][b] =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del medicamento");
           medicamentos_t [a][b+1] =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la marca medicamento");
           medicamentos_t [a][b+1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la fecha de vencimiento");
           medicamentos_t [a][b+1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la fecha de elaboración");
           
           
        }
      }
      for(int c=0; c<=num_matriz; c++){
          for(int d=0; d<=num_matriz; d++){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre del medicamento es: "+medicamentos_t [c] [d]+"La marca del medicamento es: "+medicamentos_t [c] [d+1]+"La fecha de vencimiento es: "+medicamentos_t [c] [d+1]+"La fecha de elaboración es: "+medicamentos_t [c][d+1] );
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bastaria recorrer tu matriz con un solo for,el cual este indicado por el numero de medicamentos que piensas ingresar ("a").al poner medicamentos_t [a][b+1] tres veces,lo que estas haciendo es meter diferentes datos en la misma posicion,por otro lado si pones for (int a=0; a<=4; a++), el valor de "a" deberia ser 1,pero como trabajas con matrices lo correcto es for (int a=0; a<4; a++),ya que las iteraciones se basan en los indices 0 1 2 3 ahi tienes cuatro iteraciones pero si pones a<=4 seria 0 1 2 3 4 cinco iteraciones por eso te marca error.el codigo quedaria asi

```
int num_matriz;
        
      num_matriz= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de medicamentos a cargar"));
        
      String medicamentos_t [][] = new String [num_matriz] [4];
      
      for (int a=0; a<num_matriz; a++){
         
           medicamentos_t [a][0] =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del medicamento "+(a+1));
           medicamentos_t [a][1] =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la marca medicamento");
           medicamentos_t [a][2] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la fecha de vencimiento");
           medicamentos_t [a][3] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la fecha de elaboración");      
        
      }
      for(int c=0; c<num_matriz; c++){
        
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre del medicamento "+(c+1)+" es: "+medicamentos_t [c][0]+"\nLa marca del medicamento es: "+medicamentos_t [c] [1]+"\nLa fecha de vencimiento es: "+medicamentos_t [c] [2]+"\nLa fecha de elaboración es: "+medicamentos_t [c][3] );
          }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Funciona a la perfección! Saludos!!